# Android: How can I apply a tint to a Drawable/Bitmap in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, android-bitmap, android-icons

I wanted to create a shortcut using a tinted icon, so I could not just add a tint to an ImageView. I did it this way:

```
val drawableExample: Drawable
val colorExample: Int

drawable?.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(colorExample, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)

val icon: Icon = Icon.createWithBitmap(drawable?.toBitmap(256, 256, null))
```

See the accepted answer for details on how to do this if your source image already is a Bitmap. It put me on the right track to find a slightly simpler solution that is suitable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `colorFilter`

```
val paint = Paint()
paint.setColorFilter(PorterDuffColorFilter(targetColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN))
canvas.drawBitmap(resource, matrix, paint)
```